# I'm trying to create an Fluent App in Flutter, but whenever I run it, it gives an error "Either pane or content must be provided"

Tags: flutter, dart, fluent-ui

Error:

```
Either pane or content must be provided
'package:fluent_ui/src/controls/navigation/navigation_view/view.dart':
view.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 55 pos 11: '(pane != null && content == null) || (pane == null && content != null)'
```

Code:

```
import 'package:fluent_ui/fluent_ui.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const FluentApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NavigationView(
      appBar: const NavigationAppBar(
        title: Text('Hello World!')
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I started studying this recently. What can I try to fix this?

Comment: NavigationView should have either pane or content there. Currently you just have provided appBar. Refer the basic example given here: https://pub.dev/packages/fluent_ui/changelog#400

Answer (score -2):

You need to import the material dart package as it is used for Material Design.. and in main you wrap it will MaterialApp and other class with Scaffold as it gives you all the design widget.
Copy the below code and run it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    void main() {
      runApp(const MyApp());
    }

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyApp({super.key});

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
              home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Hello World!')
      ),
    );
  }
}
```